# Can I make my plus-1 public on Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

I have +1'ed few sites, and they are showing in my Google+ profile to my "extended circles" (people in my circles and their circles). 
However, can I make my plus-ones public? The same way that I can share a link in my profile, and it is visible to everyone, even not logged-in users.

Answer (score 3):

1. Visit the **+1** tab on your profile
2. Click on the big blue **Edit** button at the top of the page.
3. Check the **Show this tab on your profile** checkbox
4. Click on the blue **Save** button below that.

+1's will now show on your profile to all users, logged in or not.

Comment: Now under the +1 tab there is a note" This tab is shown to visitors; use Google+ settings to change which tabs are visible." with a link to the settings.